# Entity Framework : Inheritance in many-many relationship not retrieving results

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

For the contrived example POCO entities:

```
public class Pet
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PetTrait> Traits { get; set; }
}

public class Dog : Pet
{
    public ICollection<DogTrait> DogTraits { get; set; }
}

public class SmallDog : Dog { }

public class LargeDog : Dog { }

public class Cat : Pet
{
    public ICollection<CatTrait> CatTraits { get; set; }
}

public class PetTrait
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Pet> PetsWithTrait { get; set; }
}

public class DogTrait : PetTrait
{
    public ICollection<Dog> DogsWithTrait { get; set; }
}

public class CatTrait : PetTrait
{
    public ICollection<Cat> CatsWithTrait { get; set; }
}
```

... Entity Framework 6 treats me pretty OK. I didn't need to do anything with the ModelBuilder (yet). The tables that are created look like:

```
Pets
    Id    Name    Discriminator
    1     Fido    SmallDog

PetTraits
    Id    Name    Discriminator
    1     Smart   DogTrait
    2     Furry   CatTrait
    3     Alive   PetTrait

PetTraitPets
    PetTrait_Id  Pet_Id
    1            1
    2            1
    3            1
```

If I execute the Find operation on the Pet's Id,

```
using (var db = new DbPets()) var pet = db.Pets.Find(1);
```

EF gets me Fido. `pet.GetType()` returns `SmallDog`, as expected. However, the `Pet.Traits` and the `Dog.DogTraits` collections are NULL.

I can understand if EF needs some help figuring out how to populate these collections correctly. Its also noteworthy that there's actually a `CatTrait` associated with Fido, even though he's a Dog. I would even expect an exception to be thrown, or some other error. But to have the Find operation succeed, return a Pet, but silently leave the collections NULL is what I don't understand.

**Question**: How can I set up the model so that these collections are populated? I would like `DogTraits` to have one entry in it, `Traits` to have 3 (even though they aren't all DogTraits).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to add `virtual` to your collection property, use a query with `db.Pets.Include(p => p.Traits)`, or use `db.Entry(pet).Collection(p => p.Traits).Load()`  so that your related objects will be there when you access the property. (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)

Second, I'm fairly certain you can't use properties in inherited types when defining a relationship between base types.

Here are some suggestions that might help you get what you want:

1. Turn your collection properties on derived types into getters that perform filtering (or essentially casting if the validation below has been done).

   ```
   public class DogTrait : PetTrait
   {
       public IEnumerable<Dog> DogsWithTrait 
       { 
           get { return PetsWithTrait.OfType<Dog>(); } 
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use validation to make sure only `Dog`s have `DogTrait`s, `Cat`s have `CatTrait`s etc.

Comment: Thanks- This added the three entities to `Pet.Traits`, and it did set all the collection values to HashSets. But the `DogTrait`s collection is still empty, when it should have one `DogTrait` in it.

Comment: @Veldaeven: sorry I was still typing more in the answer.

Comment: Actually, before I decided to go figure out what was really going on here, I had the same basic idea as you for changing the `DogsWithTrait` and the `DogTraits` to simply pass through to the more general `PetsWithTrait` and `PetTraits`, respectively. If nobody else knows of a way to do some magic in the modelBuilder, I may take this route. Thank you!!!